# Listing account names in ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am new in using ubuntu. I have searched about listing users in my machine and with less /etc/passwd i can list something like this:

`root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/bin/sh
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/bin/sh
...........
.........`

However, I want only the users that I have added with adduser command and me itself. For example my computer name is sami and I have added abc123 as user. I want something like this:

sami

abc123

How can I modify this command or is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to list all users in a read-friendly way, you can do it by typing:

`awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd`

This command will take each line, divide it by `:`, and print everything before the first `:` - and that's the name of the user.

If you want to exclude system users ("human" users, if you will), you need to exclude all users with a UID lower than 1000. You can do it like so:

`awk -F: '($3>=1000){print $1}' /etc/passwd`

This command parses each line of the `/etc/passwd` file, takes the field with the UID and prints the username only if it's bigger or equal than 1000.

Another solution is to simply list all directories in your home folder by running `ls /home` ;)